# Convert JSON array objects to .net Classes

Tags: arrays, .net, json, vb.net

I am having issues with the below JSON String on converting it to .net class. The class that I have created so far is below as well. The particular section that I cannot get to work is group_access and roles tags. I know these are an array of objects but when I try to convert the objects i get the following error; Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Array' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

I also tried using visual studio tool (Edit>Paste Special > JSON) and jscon2csharp.com it errors out on converting the roles and group_access tags.

JSON data:

```
    {
    id: 122404,
    email: 'mike@email.com',
    fname: 'Mike',
    lname: 'Doe',
    full_name: 'Mike Doe',
    resource_id: '001002',
    title: '',
    last_login: '2016-11-01 09:15:23',
    tags: [
    'Math Department', 'New Teachers'
    ],
    grades: [
    4, 5, 6
    ],
    targets: [
    'Option 1: 3 Informal Obs.'
    ],
    caseload_tags: [],
    group_access: [
    10: 2
    25527: 1
    25645: 1
    25653: 4
    ],
    roles: [
    10: [
        2015: 2,
        2016: 2
    ],
    25527: [
        2015: 2,
        2016: 1
    ]
    25645: [
        2015: 1,
        2016: 1
    ]
    25653: [
        2015: 3,
        2016: 4
    ]
    ]
    }
```

My code:

```vb
    Public Class Item
      Public Property id As Integer
      Public Property email As String
      Public Property fname As String
      Public Property lname As String
      Public Property full_name As String
      Public Property resource_id As String
      Public Property title As String
      Public Property tags As IList(Of String)
      Public Property grades As IList(Of String)
      Public Property targets As IList(Of String)
      Public Property group_access As Array
      Public Property roles As Array
    End Class

    Public Class RootObject
      Public Property type As String
      Public Property limit As Integer
      Public Property offset As Integer
      Public Property total As Integer
      Public Property time As String
      Public Property items As List(Of Item)
      Public Property items_count As Integer 
    End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is not valid - array elements must be separated with commata.

Comment: I have no control how the data is presented to me. This is how it comes from the application I am connecting to.

Comment: You got none-valid json, you cannot expect to work with it using a json library.